# Match two arrays based on keys and values

Tags: php, arrays

One array has :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> array(6) {
    ["sid"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["book_id"]=> string(3) "b_1"
    ["book_name"]=> string(9) "XYZ"
    ["time_added"]=> string(19) "2013-05-07 04:17:03"
    ["priority"]=> string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=> array(6) {
    ["sid"]=> string(1) "2"
    ["book_id"]=> string(3) "b_2"
    ["book_name"]=> string(6) "TOP"
    ["time_added"]=> string(19) "2012-11-06 08:09:56"
    ["priority"]=> string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

The second one:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=> array(15) {
    ["book_id"]=> string(3) "625"
    ["b_1"]=> string(1) "6"
    ["b_2"]=> string(1) "11"
    ["date_book_added"]=> NULL
    ["category"]=> string(7) "nv"
  }
}
```

How I can make 3rd array, where values for the keys, b_1 and b_2 will be replaced by values from the second: 6 and 11. And everything will be merged?

Comment: Can you please copy the data with the original indentation to make this more readable?

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: How did you get those arrays in the first place?

Comment: @Jack Database query.

Comment: It would help to share that background in more details; I think you're just doing it wrong.

Comment: The thing is I want to grab from array 1 - values of book_id which is b_1 and b_2, found those keys in array 2 and combine it, so the final array would be something like: book_id = 6, book_name = XYZ ... book_id = 11, book_name = TOP and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

if you want to do it iteratively over an array of arrays

```
$results = array();
foreach($array1 as $k => $v){
    $results[$k] = array_merge($v, $array3);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `$v` instead of `$array1[$k]`?